# Sitecore SXA Gallery Video item Thumbnail Image

Tags: sxa

I am using Gallery Compoent > Gallery Video item and added the image for "Custom local thumbnail" attribute which having the ALT text also, but after rendering of image, its not showing the ALT Text for image:

```
 <img width="1000" height="40" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 40px; display: block; position: absolute; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; min-width: 0px; max-width: none; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);" src="/-/media/Project/Site1/shared/Img1.png">
```

Is there any way to include image alt text in image tag?

Comment: I've checked the code and Rendering Variants are properly generating `<img  />` HTML tag with `alt` attribute but looks like JS plugin which we use for galeria is doing some tricks to the HTML and `alt` attribute is gone.

Comment: Any  alternative for that?

Comment: Probably not if you want to add ALT text to this particular image. Feel free to register Support ticker.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski: I have raised the support ticket for this https://support.sitecore.net/helpdesk/viewitem?id=528069.